# $\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)$ (if it exists), where $f(x)=\begin{cases}x-[x],&x<2\\4,&x=2\\3x-5,&x>2\end{cases}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> **Question** : Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)$ (if it exists), where $f(x)=\begin{cases}x-[x],&x<2\\[2ex]4,&x=2\\[2ex]3x-5,&x>2\end{cases}$ 
> *[.] denotes the greatest integer function*.

My attempt: 
$$\lim_{x \to 2^+} f(x) = 3(2)-5=1$$
$$\lim_{x \to 2^-} f(x) = x - [x] = 2-[2]$$
From this step onwards I am stuck and do not know how to continue. Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
f(1.999)=1.999-[1.999]=0.999\\
f(1.9)=1.9-[1.9]=0.9\\
f(1.4)=1.4-[1.4]=0.4\\
f(1.01)=1.01-[1.01]=0.01\\
f(1)=1-[1]=0
$$

It's not difficult to see that the function $x-[x]$ on the interval $[1,2)$ is equivalent to the function $x-1$. Thus, the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $2$ from the left is:

$$
\lim_{x\to 2^-}(x-[x])=\lim_{x\to 2^-}(x-1)=2-1=1.
$$

The limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $2$ from the right is simpler:

$$
\lim_{x\to 2^+}(3x-5)=3\cdot 2-5=1.
$$
Since both one-sided limits are equal to each other, the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $2$ exists and is equal to $1$:$$\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)=1.$$

Notice that I didn't even care about the fact that $f(2)=4$. It does not matter what the function $f(x)$ itself is equal to at the point $x=2$. What does matter is what's happening as we're approaching $2$. We're not checking it for continuity. In other words, even though the function $f(x)$ is indeed discontinuous at $x=2$, the limit there does exist.